# MariaDB: SELECT statement to a table from within a FUNCTION not working

Tags: function, mariadb, subquery

This is my very first function I'm creating in MariaDB v10.5.19 so I reckon I just overlook a very obvious thingy, which clearly isn't obvious for me yet.

My function stops working when it hits this condition:

`ELSEIF ( SELECT COUNT(sku) FROM user123_dbname.wp_2_wc_product_meta_lookup WHERE sku LIKE CONCAT(str, '/_%') ) >= 1`

Is it not able to execute that statement?
If so, what do I need to change to get it working?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user123`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_sku_class`(`str` VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8mb4)
RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci

BEGIN

    DECLARE sku_class VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '(undefined)';
    
    IF     str LIKE 'CQs__-_%' THEN SET sku_class = 'sample';
    ELSEIF str LIKE 'CQt__-_%' THEN SET sku_class = 'tasting';
    ELSEIF str LIKE 'CQ____/%' THEN SET sku_class = 'project-cask';
    ELSEIF str LIKE 'CX%'      THEN SET sku_class = 'misc';

    ELSEIF ( SELECT COUNT(`sku`) FROM `user123_dbname`.`wp_2_wc_product_meta_lookup` WHERE `sku` LIKE CONCAT(str, '/_%') ) >= 1 
                               THEN SET sku_class = 'project';

    ELSEIF str LIKE 'CQ____%' AND LENGTH(str) = 6 
                               THEN SET sku_class = 'cask';
    ELSE SET sku_class = '(undefined)';
    END IF;
    
    RETURN sku_class;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Btw - the `SELECT COUNT(sku) FROM user123_dbname.wp_2_wc_product_meta_lookup WHERE sku LIKE CONCAT('CQ1234', '/_%')` query works fine when running outside of the function.

Comment: Are you getting an error? I can't see any reason why that wouldn't work.

Comment: You can also use `ELSEIF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ...)`. This is likely to be more efficient since it doesn't have to find all the rows that match the condition.

Comment: How long does that query take when you run it outside the function? If you're calling the function frequently, that time will add up.

Comment: @Barmar nope, no error to help me into a direction to resolve it. Outside the function the query is just lightning fast so that's no issue although changing it into `ELSEIF EXISTS` wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Edited to make it clear you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are not the same product, and in fact they are becoming increasingly incompatible. We should all stop thinking of MariaDB as "a type of MySQL." They're basically different products by now.

Comment: Thanks Bill, that's a very valid point you make!